# Unable to Create ObjectInputStream Object

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, objectinputstream

This is my code. When I run this, I get up to "Three and a Half" printed. (The prints are added for debugging since I don't know any other way.) After that, the execution hangs. No exceptions, no prompts, nothing. So what is wrong with my object creation? Each and every tutorial I see online has the same code, but mine won't work.

```
public class Connection {
    Socket socket;
    ObjectInputStream iStream;
    ObjectOutput outputStream;

    public Connection(Socket s) {
        try {
            System.out.println("One");
            socket = s;
            System.out.println("Two");
            outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
            System.out.println("Three");
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            System.out.println("Three and a Half");
            iStream = new ObjectInputStream(is);
            System.out.println("Four");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the Javadoc:

> A serialization stream header is read from the stream and verified. This constructor will block until the corresponding ObjectOutputStream has written and flushed the header.

So the new ObjectInputStream is hanging because it's waiting on input. You need to create an ObjectOutputStream and send data through the socket.

Comment: Yes, it's desinged that way so you can wait for input inside a loop and continously handle incoming data.

Comment: @ObedMarsh No, it's designed that way to provide protocol version information among other things. Stream headers have nothing to do with loops whatsoever.

Comment: I didn't say they had anything to do with loops I said they were ideal to put inside a loop to keep accepting incoming data. So yes 99% of the time you will find it inside a loop.

Comment: No, you said "it's designed that way so you can wait for input inside a loop". It's up there in black and white. Not a word about "ideal" either. The answer is about design, and stream headers, not about loops.

Comment: I apologize sincerely for using words you could nitpick your way through, but the fact remains that 99% of all programs will be using this in a loop (and frankly if it isn't it's probably not very well made).

Comment: @ObedMarsh You don't need stream headers inside a loop. I really have no idea what you're talking about. Who or what is 'they' in your various comments?